# Precedence of operations in vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ (for simplicity) with addition denoted by $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication denoted by $\otimes$. Let $\mathbf u, \mathbf w \in V$ and let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and suppose we are asked to compute
$$
\lambda \otimes \mathbf u \oplus \mathbf v
$$
I was wondering how to do this. I would tend to say it is
$$
(\lambda \otimes \mathbf u) \oplus \mathbf w
$$
but it might as well be
$$
\lambda \otimes (\mathbf u \oplus \mathbf w)
$$
since, as far as I understand, none of the axioms for a vector space settles the precedence of scalar multiplication over vector addition. Is there a general rule for this ?

**EDIT:** 
I "know" that the cultural rule is precedence of scalar multiplication over vector addition. This is hinted at from shortcuts like 
$$
\lambda(\mathbf u + \mathbf v) = \lambda \mathbf u + \lambda \mathbf v
$$
which (I think) should be written as
$$
\lambda(\mathbf u+ \mathbf v) = (\lambda \mathbf u) + (\lambda \mathbf v) \,.
$$
unless everyone agrees beforehand that scalar multiplication takes precedence.
The thing I am wondering about is whether a computer (say) would be able to deduce this precedence from the axioms alone.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: $\lambda \otimes u\oplus v$ is not well-defined. In order to avoid such dilemmas, you either write $\lambda\otimes (u\oplus w)$ or $(\lambda\otimes u)\oplus w$.

Comment: @Levent That has to be wrong. Otherwise why would the distributive axiom be written the way it always is. We always write $\lambda(u+v)=\lambda u+\lambda v$. Are you claiming the RHS is not well-defined?

Comment: No, what I mean is $\lambda u+v$ is not well-defined, not $\lambda(u+v)=\lambda u+\lambda v$. But commonly we just use $\lambda u+v$ to denote $(\lambda u)+v$.

Comment: @Levent. You miss the point. If $\lambda u+v$ was not well-defined, then $\lambda u+\lambda v$ would not be well-defined, because it might mean $(\lambda u)+(\lambda^2v)$. But $\lambda u+\lambda v$ obviously is well-defined because it appears in the axioms. So $\lambda u+v$ is also well-defined - it means $(\lambda u)+v$.

Comment: @almagest your argument is invalid in $F_2$.

Comment: Sorry for trolling. General comment: this situation is very similar to the one in a ring e.g. $\mathbb R$. You introduce the distribution law which then allows you notation like $a(x+y)= ax+ay $ and $ax +y = y+ax$. On a more abstract level: you often omit the brackets for functions, say $f$ is a function you would write $fx$ but it only (similar to tex) means the very next argument, hence $fx+y=f(x)+y$. Now consider multiplication with $\lambda$ as a linear function (on a ring or a vector space).

Comment: @DanielValenzuela Sure. Do you really think this kind of question comes from someone who even knows what $F_2$ is?

Comment: @almagest I guess you're right.

Comment: I really was just trolling, as I often feel like doing before I go to bed. And that's why I absolutely didn't have in mind how much he knows, but more the voice I wanted to be and that was enough for me for a short laugh. Then I realized that I felt bad and I wrote a helpful comment in order to not just be useless. Now concerning *your question*: actually most schools I know they teach fields first, how would you introduce a vector space otherwise? (the first part is honestly true. I feel like maybe 80:20 ratio at least in Germany)

Comment: By convention (although I can't recall this ever being explicitly mentioned in a text) scalar multiplications are performed first, so that $\lambda u + v$ is interpreted as Levent commented above.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a **convention**. And the usual **convention** is to continue the shortcuts used for operations among numbers (and be it in order not to confuse the reader when we already reuse the notation from numeric operations for vectors). In other words, the **convention** is that $\lambda\otimes u\oplus v$ is a shorthand writing for $(\lambda\otimes u)\oplus v$. Note that it is in fact common to (re-)use the multiplication and addition symbols from numeric operations and in fact write $\lambda\cdot u+v$ or just $\lambda u+v$.

In case of a vector space with a scalar product, you may even see $\lambda \cdot u \cdot v$ (or $\lambda u v$) with the dot standing for two completely different operations. Fortunately, it is true that $(\lambda\cdot u)\cdot v=\lambda\cdot(u\cdot v)$ (an equation that even has *three* distinct operations denoted by the same dot symbol!).